# Mostra imagem em JSP

Tags: html, jsp, imagem

Estou tendo problema para mostrar uma imagem em minha página JSP. Estou tentando utilizar várias formas diferentes de pegar o arquivo e não consigo mostrá-lo na página.

As pastas estão dispostas da seguinte maneira

```
WebContent
|_1.jpg
|_ParaEmpresas.png
|_img
    |_1.jpg
    |_ParaEmpresas.png
```

O código na minha página jsp

```html
<img src="../../1.jpg"/>
<img src="<c:url value="/img/ParaEmpresas.png"/>" />
<img src="<c:url value="/ParaEmpresas.png"/>" />
```

e o erro ao tentar carregar a página

```
ADVERTÊNCIA: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/DataIdea/img/1.jpg] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc'set 08, 2015 4:13:08 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
```

WEB.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    DataIdea

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<resource-ref>
        <description>postgreSQL Datasource example</description>
         <res-ref-name>jdbc/postgres</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
         <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/views/erro/erro.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<listener>
    <listener-class>br.com.quartz.ListenToMeFirst</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Qual a diferença de diretório da sua JSP e da img? Provavelmente você está informando o caminho incorreto, você pode confirmar no console do navegador se tiver dando `erro 404`

Comment: Você tem o servlet configurado para expor o diretório publicamente?

Comment: @BrunoCésar Eu já tinha tentado usando JSP Scriplet. Tentei usar JSTL e tambem não deu.

Comment: @flpms desculpa a minha ignorancia, mas como a aplicação é grande então e eu ser novo projeto eu não tinha mexido ainda no XML, por isso atualizei a pergunta com o código. Caso precise de alguma informação me avise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma solução que eu achei foi acrescentar esse código no WEB.xml

```
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

e fazer referencia à imagem utilizando a seguinte tag

```
<img src="<c:url value="….. "/>" />
```

Utilizando essa hierarquia na pastas

```
WebContent
|_img
    |_ParaEmpresas.png
```

O código ficaria da seguinte forma

```
 <img src="<c:url value="/img/ParaEmpresas.png"/>" />
```